# Make pdf-tools do pdf-sync-forward-search after compilation

Tags: pdf-tools

Using [pdf-tools](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools) for showing pdfs in emacs is great! But when I use it, I alway have to do a (C-c C-g) i.e., pdf-sync-forward-search after compilation. How can I make emacs do this automatically?

Furthermore, I also get the error message "error in process sentinel", when emacs reverts the buffer. Can I make this go away?